# How to implement ticker callback at 100 micro seconds for ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, ticker

I have an ESP8266 NodeMCU 12E development board and I'm using the Arduino IDE.  I'm trying to use a `Ticker.h` to sample an analog input consistently at a frequency of 10khz, which is one sample every 100us.  I noticed that `Ticker sampler; sampler.attach(0.0001,callbackfunc);` didn't work because `attach()` won't take the value 0.0001.

So then I wrote the following code based on some guides that I saw:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Ticker.h>

bool s = true;
void getSample()
{
  s = !s;
}
Ticker tickerObject(getSample, 100, 0, MICROS_MICROS);

const char *ssid =  "___";  // Change it
const char *pass =  "___";  // Change it

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(0);      //start
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  tickerObject.start();

}


void loop()
{
    if(s == true)
    {
      Serial.println("True");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("False");
    }
}
```

However, this did not compile because `tickerObject.start()` method did not exist.  So what I did next was:

1. Download the latest ticker package [as a zip file](https://github.com/sstaub/Ticker)
2. Unzip the package from point 1
3. Made a back up of `C:\Users\john\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0-beta2\libraries\Ticker`
4. Replaced the folder mentioned in point 3 with the Ticker folder in point 2.
5. Restarted my Arduino IDE
6. Compiled and ran the code
7. Opened up the Serial Monitor

However, when I inspect the serial monitor, all it prints is "True". I was expecting the value `s` to toggle between true and false at a 10khz frequency.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of this library:

> The library use no interupts of the hardware timers and works with the micros() / millis() function.

This library implements timers in software by polling the `micros()` and `millis()` functions. It requires the `update()` method to be called in `loop()`.

So the start of `loop()` should be:

```
void loop()
{
    tickerObject.update();

    if(s == true)
```

> I'm trying to use a Ticker.h to sample an analog input consistently at a frequency of 10khz

It is worth a go but this is a software based solution that is prone to jitter depending on how often the event loop can be called.

Comment: Great that solved the problem. I'm going to compare against your other suggestion on my other question, which is to attempt this approach for ISR https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/10/07/esp32-arduino-timer-interrupts/

Comment: No problems. I'd be interested in your findings and how far the approach in this question gets you.